# Is there documentation for iso-scan/filename?

Tags: boot, grub2

I do not see any documentation for the boot parameter `iso-scan/filename=`. I see the parameter is handled by the script at location `scripts/casper-premount/20iso_scan` in Ubuntu's initrd. [Here is the script](//paste.ubuntu.com/11820435).

What is the closest thing to documentation that exists for this boot parameter?

Also is there any comprehensive list of the boot parameters which are available in Ubuntu?

Comment: rocky's answer is a good answer. I would like to see does anybody else have thoughts or knowledge on the matter.

Comment: Well, in the grub2 install script, one may see things like `linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/boot-repair-disk-64bit.iso splash --`.  This means that the "linux _file_" cmd of grub2 is run [(see manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#linux), and the description of that is: "_Load a Linux kernel image from file. The rest of the line is passed verbatim as the kernel command-line._" ... so anything beyond the filename is meant for kernel argument processing, which can only be doc'd on the level of a particular linux distribution, family or version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [french wikipedia article on casper](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_casper) says this (translated into English)

> The main phases starting...
>
> If requested by iso-scan / filename = / xxx, looking for an .iso image of CD whose name is / xxx

And the shell script code verifies that this is how it works.

As for a comprehensive list of boot parameters, there isn't likely to be one for such a broad question. That's like asking if there is a comprehensive list of documentation for shell scripts. Those parameters go to the thing that gets control of boot, and as far as I know anyone can write such a thing.

Answer (score 5):

The correct source for that script is from `lupin-casper` package in Ubuntu

> Description: Add support for loop-mount installations to casper  The
>   Wubi installer provides a means for installing Ubuntu into a 
>   loop-mounted filesystem image hosted on a Windows filesystem.
>   lupin-casper  provides hooks to find an ISO image on a hard disk and
>   to read a preseed  file from a hard disk, which are used in the early
>   part of this process.

An initramfs hook installs `/scripts/casper-premount/20iso_scan` inside the initramfs / initrd. If you make a custom live-build Ubuntu based ISO, you need to include that package to have Grub2 be able to live boot.

`find_iso` parameter was renamed to `iso-scan/filename=` which sets `LIVEMEDIA` which is queried in `find_livefs` in `/scripts/casper`

Without `iso_scan` script, you end up stuck in initramfs console with error message:
`unable to find a medium containing a live file system`

Example grub configuration:

```
menuentry "Ubuntu Live CD" {
    set isofile="/efi/boot/ubuntu.iso"
    loopback loop (hd0,msdos1)$isofile
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject debug
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

Hope that helps someone... finding the source of iso_scan was rather difficult.

Comment: I don't see the error message without "iso_scan". Instead, I found that I can just copy all the files of the ubuntu live dvd to a hard drive partition and boot from there (no setting loopback and replacing `(loop)` with `(hd0,msdos1)`).